# How to build desktop app from my website?

Tags: node.js, gulp, nw.js

I see this github project: https://github.com/Aluxian/WhatsApp-Desktop. I don't know how to build a desktop app (exe) or mac app(dmg) from that github source code. who added on github not say clear for understand. Can anyone tell me step by step tutorial on that project. please, i'm a new guy. (sorry for my english).

Answer (score 0):

The instructions are on the project's homepage under the [Build section](https://github.com/Aluxian/WhatsApp-Desktop#build).

For both systems you will need to install Node.js (using one of the [installers](https://nodejs.org/en/) from nodejs.org). This will also install npm (Node's package manager) on your system.

Then, open a command prompt and install gulp globally:

```
npm install -g gulp
```

To make the Windows installer, you'll also need to download and install [makensis](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).

Next, grab the project's source from GitHub. If you have git installed do it like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/Aluxian/WhatsApp-Desktop.git
```

Otherwise, download and unpack the source files from the project's page directly (using the "Download" button in the top right of the screen).

Navigate to the directory to which you have downloaded the source files and run the appropriate gulp task.

```
// OS X: pack the app in a .dmg
gulp pack:osx64
```

Or

```
// Windows: create the installer
gulp pack:win32
```

The output will be in the `./dist` folder.

Comment: thank you so much. but how to put source code file in command to build gulp? from    " // OS X: pack the app in a .dmg" i don't understand. is we write : cd  (source file) , enter , then what?

Comment: You need to run the command `gulp pack:osx64` from the terminal.

Comment: what is mean "Navigate to the directory to which you have downloaded the source files". what we write in command?

Comment: `cd WhatsApp-Desktop`

Comment: i don't choice use "git clone" download. i download source file, exstract, put in folder, name is "whatsapp desktop". how we gonna put this source file to terminal to build?

Comment: Go into the folder `whatsapp desktop`. Open a terminal. Run `gulp pack:osx64`

Comment: did we copy cmd.exe into folder "whatsapp desktop" and run, and write?

Comment: Sorry, if you can't follow what I've written above, I don't think you stand much chance of getting things to work. You need to open cmd in the "whatsapp desktop" folder, or open it elsewhere and navigate there.

Comment: I understand now. BUT, i type for install gulp, it become like this: "lodash@<2.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0". what is this mean? i do nothing wrong.!

Comment: No probs. Please accept my answer if it solved your problem.